# Get count against each distinct value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl_demo` like this:

```
              aliasname is_correct
                    10  INCORRECT
                    10  INCORRECT
                    10  INCORRECT
                    10  CORRECT
                    10  CORRECT
                    10  NOT SOLVED
                    9   INCORRECT
                    9   INCORRECT
                    9   CORRECT
```

I created a query:

```
select 
    aliasname, 
    count(*) as quest_count,  
    is_correct 
from 
    tbl_demo 
group by 
    aliasname, is_correct order by aliasname
```

and I get output like this

```
              aliasname quest_count  is_correct
              ---------------------------------
              10          2            CORRECT
              10          3            INCORRECT
              10          1            NOT SOLVED
               9          1            CORRECT
               9          2            INCORRECT
```

but I want 0 for in 9 and NOT solved

Like one more row like this

```
                9         0            NOT SOLVED
```

Can this be achieved easily, and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by generating all possible combinations using `cross join`, and the using `left join` to bring in the original data.  The rest is just aggregation:

```
select a.aliasname, count(d.aliasname) as quest_count, ic.is_correct
from (select distinct aliasname from tbl_demo
     ) a cross join
     (select distinct is_correct from tbl_demo
     ) ic left outer join
     tbl_demo d
     on d.aliasname = a.aliasname and d.is_correct = ic.is_correct
group by a.aliasname, ic.is_correct;
```